# I'm trying to open url but its showing nothing (empty page) other urls are working?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i'm using Linux Ubuntu python and selenium and trying open url but it's showing me empty page..

```
self.driver.get(self.pro_url)
```

and my url is https://www.reebonz.com/us/women/designer-clothing?pagesize=48&PageNumber=1

Comment: It's Security Problem i'm sorry i can't fix it!

Comment: security means reebonz does not allow to scrap data from there website..?

Comment: yes But Any Expert Can Bypass This Security

Comment: Okay thanks let me know if you find any solution